# how to change ag-grid row count?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a ag-grid row group example setup here: https://plnkr.co/edit/lOOhfLcpuNbIgXO5e7Wy?p=preview

```html
var columnDefs = [

    {
        headerName: 'country',
        rowGroup: 'true',
        showRowGroup: true,
        cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
        field: 'country',
        cellRendererParams: {
            suppressCount: true,
            checkbox: false,
            innerRenderer: 'simpleCellRenderer',
            suppressDoubleClickExpand: true,
            suppressEnterExpand: true
        }
    },

    {headerName: 'City', field: 'city', cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',        cellRendererParams: {
            suppressCount: true,
            checkbox: false,
            innerRenderer: 'simpleCellRenderer',
            suppressDoubleClickExpand: true,
            suppressEnterExpand: true
        }}

];
```

In this example I am specifying suppressCount to be true, after which I expected to see the row count of only countries but the grid shows a total row count of 27. How do I make it count only the unique countries and ignore the rows for each city.

reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: And where would you want the count to be placed at?

Comment: The count is already displayed when pagination is enabled on the lower right corner